# How to make a console app that excutes a command only when called

Tags: c++, cmd, console, console-application

I am working on a project that has some functionality similar to windows task manager but as a console app. So far I managed to make the app present menus and, according to the user's choice, the app runs a specific functionality.

Now, I am thinking of letting the app do some function using commands for example, let's say we have the command `close -all`. This is supposed to close all the open windows.

In fact, I have some information about how I can process the command and call the corresponding function, I think using a lexer to produce tokens and then use a parser to call the functions, please correct me if I am mistaken.

However I can use the commands only if my application is running in cmd. what I want is to call a command like `wg close all` (wg being the app name) at any time and then maybe continue running other cmd commands like `mkdir` or `cd`.

Comment: In my opinion, you need to create a bash script which include ur custom commands..

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you need the basic functionality of a C++ program which is provided by the `main(int argc, char* argv[])` method (refer to this documentation if needed: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function).

With `argc` being the number of arguments and `argv` being an array with the values of arguments. I assume that your application builds up a GUI with Qt or some library, which you would not need to fire up if ran in batch mode.

Depending on the complexity of the arguments you need to handle, you might do the trick with a very basic structure to parse the arguments.

Example Pseudo-Code

```
main(argc, argv) {

  if (argc == 0) {
    startProgramInNormalGUIMode();
    exit(0);
  }

  // This could be a sub method "parse(argc, argv)"

  String parameter="";
  Boolean executed=false;

  for (i=0; i < argc; ++i) {

    if element == "close" {
      set parameter = argv[i+1];
      i++;  // skip next element which was the parameter

      // myCloseOperation would check if parameter is 
      // "all" for example and closes all windows
      // or treat any other value as window title for 
      // example and closes only the matching window.
      myCloseOperation(parameter);
      set executed = true;
    }

    if element == "operation2" {
      set parameter = argv[i+1];
      i++;

      myOperation2Method(parameter);
      set executed = true;
    }
  }

  if (executed == false) {
    showSyntaxErrorMessage();
    exit(1);
  }

  exit(0);

}
```

The pseudo code above assumes that every operation has an identifying name and only one parameter following it. You could alter the code to also allow zero parameters or more than one and change the `i` incrementation accordingly.

You could also add a check if a parameter or operation string starts with a dash or slash or some other prefix you want.

Also it is assumed that an operation and its parameter(s) may occur more than once in the command line and every occurance would be executed. For example `wg close aWindowTitle close anotherWindowTitle close all` would be parsed as valid and three close operations would be performed.